# Why do some websites contain "www-alt" instead of "www" in the address bar?

Tags: http, url, networking, browser, server-side

I recently stumbled upon a domain (http://www-alt.ncbex.org) that contained `www-alt` in its URL instead of the expected `www`. It appears that visiting the site using both `www` and `www-alt` lead to the same page source, but interestingly Google Search (https://www.google.com/search?q=mee+sample+%22twenty+years+ago%22+ube&oq=) has crawled and stored the `www-alt` version. I did a little digging and was unable to find any standard of the `www-alt` format, although I admit my search was limited to 15-20 minutes.

Anyone have any ideas about how to implement a `www-alt` prefix to the URL, or alternatively, have any links to specifications regarding it?

Comment: There is no standard or meaning to www-alt as far as I know.  It's probably just a mis-configuration or copy of the site they use for testing that got accidentally indexed.

Comment: It's just a name.